# Bash trying to set, create and re-use variables

Tags: bash

Thanks to:
@Diego Torres Milano

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569466/175063

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home -type f -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | while read -rd $'\x00' f
do
    cat '[%s]\n' "$f" | grep DB_NAME
done
```

But, seems to be missing something:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home -type f -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | while read -rd $'\x00' f
do
    cat '[%s]\n' "$f" | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4
done
```

With the results of:

```
./test.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./test.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Ultimately, I want something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home -type f -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | while read -rd $'\x00' f
do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
    WPDBNAME=`cat '%s\n' "$f" | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4
    WPDBUSER=`cat '%s\n' "$f" | grep DB_USER | cut -d \' -f 4
    WPDBPASS=`cat '%s\n' "$f" | grep DB_PASSWORD | cut -d \' -f 4
    echo $WPDBNAME
    echo $WPDBUSER
    echo $WPDBPASS
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: There's an extra backtick at the end of -f 4`

Comment: If you just link to an older question of yours to explain what's going on, the current question isn't self-contained. To understand it, I have to go elsewhere first. You should describe what you're trying to do and what happened instead in the question itself.

Comment: Do you mean `printf` instead of `cat`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here; to begin with, I'll second @Cyrus' recommendation of [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll spot a number of common errors, including several in your script. Anyway, the problems I see are:

- The error you're getting is due to unbalanced backquotes. The original version of the question had this line:

  ```
  cat '[%s]\n' "$f" | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4`
  ```

  and that lone backquote at the end of the line will cause errors like the one you're getting. The edited version doesn't have that (and as a result will not give the reported error), but the "I want something along the lines of" script has lines like:

  ```
  WPDBNAME=`cat '%s\n' "$f" | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4
  ```

  which has an unmatched backquote right after the `=`. My recommendation is to use `$( )` instead of backquotes -- they're much easier to read (and hence harder to mess up), functionally equivalent, and don't have the subtle escaping issues that backquotes cause. So, you should use something like:

  ```
  WPDBNAME=$(cat '%s\n' "$f" | grep DB_PASSWORD | cut -d \' -f 4)
  ```
- Except that that's still wrong. The `'%s\n'` part is a `printf` format string, which was needed in the example you copied, but is completely irrelevant here. If you give that argument to the `cat` command, it'll try to open a file named `%s\n` and fail. Just leave that off:

  ```
  WPDBNAME=$(cat "$f" | grep DB_PASSWORD | cut -d \' -f 4)
  ```
- This next one isn't really a problem, so much as a general recommendation: anytime you see `cat somefile | somethingcommand`, the `cat` command isn't actually doing anything useful (it's known as a "useless use of cat"). It can be replaced by `somecommand <somefile` or, if the command supports input filenames directly, `somecommand somefile`. `grep` supports input filenames, so you can just use `grep DB_PASSWORD "$f"`.
- Actually, `grep something | cut something` can almost always be simplified by using `awk` instead. Just use `/pattern/` to search for relevant lines, and `print` the relevant fields (using `-F` to define the field separator):

  ```
  WPDBNAME=$(awk -F \' '/DB_NAME/ {print $4}' "$f")
  ```
- You aren't running into this problem, but using all-caps variable names can cause trouble and is generally considered a bad practice. There are a number of variables that have special meaning to the shell and/or other programs, and if you accidentally use one of those it can have bad/weird effects. The classic case is using `PATH` for something other than the list of places to look for executables, and then [suddenly getting "command not found" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826442/mkdir-command-not-found-in-bash-script/29828056).

  Just stick to lowercase or mixed-case variables, and you won't have to worry about this.
- When you print the results, you don't double-quote the variables. Use `echo "$wpdbname"` instead of `echo $wpdbname` to prevent parsing oddities due to word splitting and glob expansion.
- But actually, you don't need to capture the various parameters to variables at all, you can just print them directly. That is, replace:

  ```
  wpdbname=$(awk -F \' '/DB_NAME/ {print $4}' "$f")
  echo "$wpdbname"
  ```

  with:

  ```
  awk -F \' '/DB_NAME/ {print $4}' "$f"
  ```

Final script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home -type f -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | while read -rd $'\x00' f
do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
    awk -F \' '/DB_NAME/ {print $4}' "$f"
    awk -F \' '/DB_USER/ {print $4}' "$f"
    awk -F \' '/DB_PASSWORD/ {print $4}' "$f"
done
```

Note: it'd sort of be possible to replace the separate `awk` commands with a single one that searched for & printed all three values. But that'd print them in the order they occur in the file, not necessarily the order you expect. So this is probably better.

Comment: Re: single awk run -- you could print all the values from a single `END` block in chosen order.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True, but that makes the `awk` script quite a bit more complicated. Unless the file's likely to be large (so scanning it 3 times takes noticeable time), I prefer the simple brute force approach.

Answer (score 0):

With guidance from responders here, I have been able to get to a resolution and below is now what is running as a cron job.

```
#!/bin/bash
# delete files older than 7 days
find /home/dummyacount/sqlbackups/ -type f -name '*.gz' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
# set a date variable
DT=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
find /home -type f -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | while read -rd $'\x00' f
do
        printf '%s\n' "$f"
        WPDBHOST=$(grep DB_HOST '%s\n' "$f" | cut -d \' -f 4)
        WPDBNAME=$(grep DB_NAME '%s\n' "$f" | cut -d \' -f 4)
        WPDBUSER=$(grep DB_USER '%s\n' "$f" | cut -d \' -f 4)
        WPDBPASS=$(grep DB_PASSWORD '%s\n' "$f" | cut -d \' -f 4)
        mysqldump -q -u "$WPDBUSER" -h "$WPDBHOST" -p "$WPDBPASS" "$WPDBNAME" | gzip -9 > "/home/dummyaccount/sqlbackups/$DT-$WPDBNAME.sql.gz"
done
```

I also had to go back over to: https://tomjn.com/2014/03/01/wordpress-bash-magic/

to get some more of the syntax sorted out with mysqldump, but this is now working great.

Comment: `cat '%s\n' "$f"` is trying to read a file named `%s\n` before reading your `"$f"`. That's surely incorrect. It's also far less efficient than just running `grep DB_HOST "$f"`, or using the single-`awk` suggestions you were also given on the other question.

Comment: Also, this retains a bunch of quoting-related bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ will identify. Use it, trust it, &c.

Comment: (as for "working great" -- let me suggest running `exec 2>/tmp/my-cron.log` to dump its stderr to a logfile; you'll see, at minimum, an error message printed by every one of your unnecessary `cat` commands).